# Call controller method with rails-Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to execute a Ruby method in my application_controller.rb from a button in my view.
In a post yesterday, someone told me to use an Ajax call to do so because, without it, would just run on page load.

I'm very new to this and I have a hard time understanding it.

I installed the rails-Ajax gem, and it is added to my Gem file.

I followed "[Integrate Ajax capabilities to Rails websites with history, bookmarking, partial refreshes, Rails flashes, user callbacks, scripts execution, redirections.](http://rails-ajax.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)" untill step 5.

I just don't know what to do it next.

Here is my current configuration. The method only runs on page load:

My view:

```
<td><button type="button" onclick="executeit()" class="btn btn- default">executer</button></td>

<script>
function executeit() {
 var selectingCommand = document.getElementById("CommandSelect");
 var selectedCommand = selectingCommand.options[selectingCommand.selectedIndex].text;
 var selectingServer = document.getElementById("serverlist");
 var selectedServer = selectingServer.options[selectingServer.selectedIndex].text;
 var username=document.getElementById("login").text;
 var password=document.getElementById("password").text;



<%execute%>;

}
</script>
```

My method in application_controller.rb :

```
def execute
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'net/ssh'

  @hostname = "smtlmon02"
  @username = "test"
  @password = "1234"
  @cmd = "ls -al"
  @cmd2 = "sudo su - -c 'ls;date'"
  @cmd3 = "ls -alrt"

  ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password)
  res = ssh.exec!(@cmd)
  res2 = ssh.exec!(@cmd2)

  ssh.close
  puts res2

end
```

It would be fantastic if anyone could explain how to do it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure I see your goal completely, however, if you just want to call a controller action when clicking on your button, I would approach it like this:

Here the HTML:

```
<a href='#' id='executer-button' class='btn btn-default'>Executer</a>
```

You should place this in you `app/assets/javascripts/execute_caller.js`:

```js
//This function calls the "execute" controller action, using its route and also
//passes a "selectingCommand" variable to it
var callExecuter=function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'/executer_route',
    data: { selectingCommand : document.getElementById("CommandSelect"); 
          },
    success:function(){
      //I assume you want to do something on controller action execution success?
      $(this).addClass('done');
    }
  });
}

$(document).on("click","#executer-button",callExecuter);
```

Then:

1. Check your `rake routes` to see which is the appropiate route to the controller action `execute`.
2. Replace it in the `url` field of the `$.ajax(...)` function.
3. Assuming you have either `debugger`or `pry` gem, write `debugger` inside your `def execute` action controller, to make sure you reach there via ajax.
4. Edit your on `success` action in the ajax call accordingly, so it does what you want it to do.

Comment: What does the `data:`-line do? Is it necessary? I'm working on a pretty similar problem.

Comment: Can I somehow pass information to it? Like `this.getAttribute('w_id');`

Comment: that is exactly what `data:` does, it's used to attach data to the request, in the example I'm sending `document.getElementById("CommandSelect")` as `selectingCommand` variable, which will be present in `params[:selectionCommand]` inside the controller. Also I recommend you to start a new question even if the issue is similar ;)

Comment: As much as I appreciate the answer, 'execute' as sample controller name is melting mind of a reader here... Why not something actually meaningful?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using jQuery, you could add this:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        context: document.body
    }).done(
        function() {
            $( this ).addClass( "done" );
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Can I kindly ask in which file I have to use this code ? :)

Comment: I will take a guess here, correct me if I am wrong:

I need to replace "button" by my button's id.
I need to replace function() by my method's name: "execute"
And I need to replace test.html by my view's name : "test.html.erb"
?

Comment: Hi,

I just can't seem to understamd how to make it work..

Could you please explain a little bit more ?

Comment: This is not a complete answer. Please, explain further so that all can understand how you got to this code.